# remove colors from image

Tags: image, colors

I'm in the process of OCRing data from IDs and driver licenses, but I find that the often very colorful decorations interfere with the OCR quality. I would like to be able to remove all not-almost-black colors from an image and replace them with white. I can write a little program that does this on a pixel by pixel level, but there probably is some batch tool or (Java) library that can do this much better and prevents me from writing parsers for all kinds of formats.

Any pointers?

Comment: See and search for [Thresholding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thresholding_(image_processing))

Comment: I hoped for a reference to some existing library.

Answer (score 0):

The best method I've found is using Photo Editor Online (http://pixlr.com/editor). It's great for making coloring pages for kids. After saving an image, open it in PEO and click on the "Filter" tab. Scroll down to the bottom of that and select "Find edges". The image will then change color. Next, click on "adjustment" and scroll down to "invert" and click on that. Voila! Save your image outline. If the lines are too light, you can insert the image into MS Word, go into picture edit mode and decrease the contrast.

Comment: There are many good programs that can do this, but the "batch" part was quite important. By now I've written a custom Java program to do this.